# Will my programs work if I move my 'Program Files' folder and then place it back to a partition with the same label?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I need some extra space in my 'C:\' partition and for doing that I need to delete my 'D:\' partition. The thing is I've got my softwares installed in 'D:\Program Files'. So my question is, will my programs work all right if I cut and paste the directory to another partition, and then move them back to a newly created partition (from the unallocated space left after extending 'C:\') with the same label ('D:\') as before.
I understand that there are registry pointers. I was wondering if they work at the same level of abstraction as that of the disk paths.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be able to resize your C partition by only resizing your D partition. See: http://gparted.org/

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work. Windows accesses the partitions by drive-letters, so if you create a new partition and assign the same drive-letter ( in your case `D:`) and then copy the folder `Program Files` to the new `D:`-partition everything works like before. Remind that `D:` is a drive-letter, not a label, only the drive-letter is important here.

Another way is to shrink the `D:`-partition an afterwards increasing the size of `C:` which might be more convenient as you don't need to copy the files two times.

Always back-up your system and your data before playing around with partitioning!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the mount option in NTFS.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321(v=ws.11).aspx
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_volume_mount_point

In this way you will mount the partition on the c:\program files path.

You have to backup your actual c:\program files before.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: You should quote the relevant information from your link

Answer (score -1):

Should be fine, as long as there are no processes running or reading from that path when you temporarily move it to the C drive. A tool such as Unlocker should pick these up.

As an aside, you could leave your Program Files on the C drive and create a junction to it on the D drive.